# How to upload image in codeigniter using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, codeigniter

Here is my code,
Please check this, Iam trying to upload image its not working. Iam passing data through ajax using id.

Iam getting image name, while passing through codeigniter its showing error undefined user_img

Below code is Ajax

```
$('#profile_set').validate({

            submitHandler: function(form) {

                user_zip = $("#user_zip").val();
                first_name = $("#xx_first_name").val(); 
                db_email = $("#db_email").val(); 
                datepicker = $("#datepicker").val(); 
                last_name = $("#xx_last_name").val();
                new_image = $("#new_image").val();

                $.ajax({
                    url: "<?php echo base_url('myaccount/profile/'.$this->session->userdata('id').''); ?>",
                    type: "post",
                    fileElementId   :'new_image',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        xx_first_name: first_name,
                        xx_last_name: last_name,
                        db_email: db_email,
                        db_dob: datepicker,
                        user_zip: user_zip,
                        user_img: new_image
                        },
                    success: function (data) {
                        if(data.status == 'success'){
                            $('#message').removeClass('alert alert-danger');
                            $('#message').addClass('alert alert-success');
                            $('#message').empty();
                            $('#message').append(data.message); 
                            $('#message').fadeOut(3000);
                        }
                        else if(data.status == 'fail') {
                            $('#message').removeClass('alert alert-success');
                            $('#message').addClass('alert alert-danger');
                            $('#message').empty();
                            $('#message').append(data.message);
                        }
                    }

                }); 
            }
        });
```

In this function am getting image name, Its showing undefined index of profile_img['file_name'  => $_FILES['user_img']['name'] ]

```
public function profile($id)
{
    $user_id = $id;

    $profile_img = $this->input->post('user_img');


    if ($user_id !== '' AND $user_id > 0) {

        if(!empty($profile_img)){

            $uploadconfig = array(
                    'upload_path' => './uploads/',
                    'allowed_types' => 'gif|jpg|png',
                    'max_size' => '204800',
                    'file_name'  => $_FILES['user_img']['name'],
                    'encrypt_name' => TRUE
                );

                print_r($uploadconfig); exit;

                $this->load->library('upload', $uploadconfig);          

                if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload("user_img")) {
                    echo "failed to upload file(s)";
                }
                $this->upload->initialize($uploadconfig);
                $this->upload->do_upload("user_img");
                $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
                $user_profile = $upload_data['file_name'];

                $data = array();
                $data['first_name'] = $this->input->post('xx_first_name');
                $data['last_name'] = $this->input->post('xx_last_name');
                $data['email'] = $this->input->post('db_email');
                $data['user_dob'] = $this->input->post('db_dob');
                $data['user_zip'] = $this->input->post('user_zip'); 
                $data['user_img'] = $user_profile;              
        }

        else {

            $data = array();
            $data['first_name'] = $this->input->post('xx_first_name');
            $data['last_name'] = $this->input->post('xx_last_name');
            $data['email'] = $this->input->post('db_email');
            $data['user_dob'] = $this->input->post('db_dob');
            $data['user_zip'] = $this->input->post('user_zip');
        }

        $update_set = $this->users->update($id, $data);

        if ($update_set)
        {
            $ret['status'] = 'success';
            $ret['message'] = 'Updated successfully';
            echo json_encode($ret);
        }
        else
        {
            $ret['status'] = 'fail';
            $ret['message'] = 'Error while updating';
            echo json_encode($ret);
        }   
    }
}
```

My forum Code

```
<div class="account_forum" id="profile">
                    <h2 class="forum_title">Profile</h2>            
                     <form id="profile_set">
                        <div class="row row_space"> 
                            <div class="col-md-10">                         
                                <a class="profile-pic" id="existing_pic">
                                  <div class="profile-pic" style="background-image: url('<?php echo base_url('uploads/')?><?php echo @$users->user_img ?>')" >
                                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></span>
                                      <span>Change Image</span>
                                  </div>
                                </a>
                              <input type='file' name="new_image" id="new_image" onchange="readURL(this);" style="display:none;" />
                                <a class="profile-pic" id="new_upload">
                                  <div class="profile-pic" id="view_image">
                                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></span>
                                      <span>Change Image</span>
                                  </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>  

                        <div class="row row_space">
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <label>First Name</label>
                                <input type="text" name="xx_first_name" id="xx_first_name" class="form-control" placeholder="John" value="<?php echo set_value('xx_first_name', @$users->first_name);?>" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <label>Last Name</label>
                                <input type="text" name="xx_last_name" id="xx_last_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Doe" value="<?php echo set_value('xx_last_name', @$users->last_name);?>" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>  
                        <div class="row row_space">
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <label>Email</label>
                                <input type="text" name="db_email" class="form-control" id="db_email" placeholder="jdoe@gmail.com" value="<?php echo set_value('db_email', @$users->email);?>" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <label>Birthday</label>
                                <input type="text" name="db_dob" class="form-control" data-toggle="datepicker" placeholder="00/0/0000" id="datepicker" value="<?php echo set_value('db_dob', @$users->user_dob);?>" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>  
                        <div class="row row_space">
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <label>Postal Code</label>
                                <input type="text" id="user_zip" name="user_zip" class="form-control" placeholder="00000" value="<?php echo set_value('xx_user_zip', @$users->user_zip);?>" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>  
                        <input type="hidden"  id="profile_old"  name="profile_old"  value="<?php $users->user_img; ?>">
                        <div class="row row_space">
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <button type="submit" name="" class="acct_btn" value="Update">Update Profile</button>   
                            </div>
                        </div>
                     </form>                    
                </div>
```

Comment: are you getting an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for upload new image to server with ajax, you need to use `new FormData()`:

```
var fd = new FormData();    
fd.append( 'user_zip', user_zip);
fd.append( 'xx_first_name', first_name);
fd.append( 'db_email', db_email);
fd.append( 'db_dob', datepicker);
fd.append( 'xx_last_name', last_name);
fd.append( 'user_img', $('#new_image')[0].files[0]);

$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo base_url('myaccount/profile/'.$this->session->userdata('id').''); ?>",
    type: "post",
    data: fd,
    success: function () {
        // do something
    }
});
```